# Bivariate and Marginal Probability Distributions: find the value of k that makes this a probability distribution

Tags: probability

### Question:

An environmental engineer measures the amount (by weight) of particulate pollution in air samples (of a certain volume) collected over the smokestack of a coal-fueled power plant. Let $X$ denote the amount of pollutant per sample when a certain cleaning device on the stack is not operating, and let $Y$ denote the amount of pollutants per sample when the cleaning device is operating under similar environmental conditions. It is observed that $X$ is always greater than $2Y$, and the relative frequency of ($X, Y$) can be modeled by:

$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} 
      k, & 0\leq x\leq 2,0\leq y\leq 1,2y\leq x \\
      0, & elsewhere \\ 
   \end{cases}$

(In other words, $X$ and $Y$ are randomly distributed over the region inside the triangle bounded by $x =2$, $y =0$, and $2y =x$.)

**Find the value of k that makes this a probability density function.**

### Attempted Solution:

Normally, I would take an appropriate double integral and set it equal to 1. However, I'm not sure how to deal with the $2y\leq x$ in particular, so I don't know what said appropriate double integral is.

Edit: Would it be correct to compute $\int_0^1\int_0^2\frac{1}{2}xdxdy=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch the following equations on a Cartesian coordinate plane:  $$x = 0, \quad x = 2, \quad y = 0, \quad y = 1, \quad 2y = x.$$  Clearly, these are all lines in the plane.

Now shade in the region enclosed by these lines, such that: $$0 \le x \le 2, \quad 0 \le y \le 1, \quad 2y \le x.$$

What is the area of this region?  It might help to find the coordinates of any points of intersection; i.e., the vertices of the region of interest.  Use elementary geometry.  What would $k$ have to be in order for the integral of the PDF be equal to $1$?

Comment: Given $A=\frac{1}{2}b\cdot h$, with $h=1$ and $b=2$, $A=1$. So this would imply that $k=1$?

Comment: @lollercide Yes, that is correct.  For your benefit, the way the integral should be set up is $$\int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=0}^{x/2} k \, dy \, dx = 1.$$  Alternatively, if integrating in the reverse order, $$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=2y}^2 k \, dx \, dy = 1.$$  Either one results in the same solution for $k$.